# Why this stabilisation issue occurs for this waveform?

Tags: oscillator, stability, waveform

I'm using this simple wave folding schematic:

[image]

This would be best described with two short videos. Both videos have triangle input into wave folder, and I am changing the amplitude with trimpot.
**[First](https://streamable.com/0j4623)** video is how it looks straight out of buffer without any load attached on output.
The **[second](https://streamable.com/tboltx)** video is what happens when I attach small audio speakers with built in amplifier.

This module is additional output to my audio oscillator, none of the other regular wave shapes (triangle/pulse/saw/sine) behave this way. I'm sure I could clean it up with higher stabilising capacitor value 33p-75p, but I would like to understand why this is issue for this particular wave-shape.

**ADD due comments:**

The transistor stage at the left looks at first idiotic because it distorts the triangle wave. But that distortion  is the actual clou of the whole circuit. I's needed to make the triangle wave richer sounding due the generated harmonics. The question was why the system isn't stable if a speaker is connected to the output? The circuit starts to oscillate with high frequency as the video 2 shows.

Comment: So, what's the problem and have you tried a simulation?

Comment: Are you sure you want the continuous base current path from the upper transistor base into the lower transistor base to exist? The triangle wave output can sink only partially what's available . If the triangle wave is disconnected or far from the plusminus maximum output both transistors are conducting as saturated. Consider to connect the triangle wave directly to the plus input of your leftmost opamp.

Comment: @user287001 but that would disconnect the actual wave-folding part of the circuit - https://www.elby-designs.com/webtek/cgs/cgs52/cgs52_folder.html .
@ Andyaka I have tried simple simulation. My question was why the output of this wave gets so distorted when attaching a speaker/load. But other outputs like triangle/sine etc  are exactly the same.

Comment: Seemingly you want the very radically distorted result that the base current path causes, so my comment was useless.

Comment: Built on a solderless breadboard with stray capacitance coupling the output back to the input of the first opamp?

Comment: @Audioguru could you please explain in beginner friendly language? Or with a quick sketch.

Comment: The many rows of intermittent contacts and long wire jumpers all over the place on a solderless breadboard are antennas that pickup all kinds of interference and cause a circuit to oscillate. When the stray capacitance of some of the wires feeds the output back to the input then the circuit oscillates.